# Most efficient and effective way to create a surface from 3d points

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, point-clouds, normals

Say I had a point cloud with n number of points in 3d space(relatively densely packed together). What is the most efficient way to create a surface that goes contains every single point in it and lets me calculate values such as the normal and curvature at some point on the surface that was created? I also need to be able to create this surface as fast as possible(a few milliseconds hopefully working with python) and it can be assumed that n < 1000.

Comment: What are the restrictions? If the surface of the point cloud can be assumed to be "never concave" it becomes a lot easier; and if the surface can be concave then you end up with the 3D version of the coastline paradox (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox ).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "most efficient and effective" way (this is true of any problem in any domain).

In the first place, the surface you have in mind is not mathematically defined uniquely.

A possible approach is by means of the so-called Alpha-shapes, implemented either from a Delaunay tetrahedrization, or by the ball-pivoting method. For other methods, lookup "mesh reconstruction" or "surface reconstruction".

On another hand, normals and curvature can be computed locally, from neighbors configurations, without reconstructing a surface (though there is an ambiguity on the orientation of the normals).

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest Nina Amenta's [Power Crust](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Eamenta/powercrust.html) algorithm (link to [code](https://github.com/kubkon/powercrust)), or also [meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net/) suite, which can compute the curvatures too.